# Column is accepting unique value only, but no unique key or primary key is associated with that column?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Problem is because of any other constraint or because of index or any other thing?

Comment: Maybe there is unique index for that column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have unique index on this column.